Spirngboot plugin for Intelij - cannot see springboot assist option under NewProject
I have tried to add a Spring-boot assist plugin using a YouTube tutorial, but I am not getting the options to ACCEPT download etc. so am unable to update the test.yml. Also,
I only get Apply and OK. The issues are shown in these images:


How to install this successfully and code Springboot assist as a New Project?

As per 1st screenshot required plugin already installed in your IntelliJ

ya but still am unable to see that option when i create a new project

I believe this plugin we used for autoCompletion here.
